# Split string into two parts at double consonants in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm currently working on a code to translate lines of text into a variation of pig latin, 
and one of the requirements is that at any occurrence of a double consonant (bb, cc, dd, etc.)
the string needs to split between those two consonants and reform the word to look like:
"s" + part 2 + part 1 + "s".

The first part of my code is

```
raw = input("Enter a line to be translated: ")
words = raw.split()
for word in words:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example input/output: "hello, I am Sammy, nice to meet you" = "slohels, I am smysams, nice to meet you"

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: And please elaborate on how the result should be. What do you want to be returned if the string 'abc kka lbbi' is passed?

Comment: The problem is I'm not even remotely sure how to approach this problem.  If the input was "I am going to apply for a job" the return would be (ignoring the other parameters for the pig latin) "I am going to splyaps for a job"

so in your example, 'abc kka, Ibbi' returns 'abc skaks sbiibs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help you on the way a bit.

```
double_consonants = [2*c for c in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz']

for word in raw:
    for d_c in double_consonants:
        if d_c in word:
            # You should be able to finish this bit yourself
```

You should have a look at the [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) methods. Tip: Try:

```
>> s = "I am going to apply for a job".split('pp')
```

What does that return? Another tip is to use something like the code above, and place it inside a for loop. Maybe you should split the springs into a list of words first?

**Edit:** The reason I don't give you the entire answer here, is that I suspect that this is a homework assignment.

Comment: It returns ['I am going to a', 'ly for a job'].

Comment: The trickiest part of this for me to understand is that I won't know the string being input, so I won't know which double consonants, if any, will be entered.  I need a way that will detect ANY double consonant and run accordingly.  

If there is a way to split it into two variables, that would be preferred. i.e. "apply" would create part_1 = "ap" and part_2 = "ply"

Comment: Maybe you should create an array `['bb', 'cc', ..., 'zz']`, and check for occurrences of each of this elements inside a for loop?

Comment: And you are correct to assume it is homework, and I don't want an exact answer, just more of a method to reach the answer.  I was sick for the week that this was covered in my class and I am still too sick to go to see my professor for help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use regular expression here...

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'hello, I am Sammy, nice to meet you'
>>> re.sub('((\w*([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]))(\\3\w*))', 's\\4\\2s', s)
'slohels, I am smySams, nice to meet you'
```

Almost there... :)

Comment: then lowercase it all

Comment: Well, Mr. @user2977230 would probably have to convince his teacher that this is his work. I'm guessing he's going to have a hard time to achieve that using this code.